# #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to move my database from my usbwebserver to my online server. But I get this error, can anyone help me with this?

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: Empty the database on the online server.

Comment: Please accept answer if it helps you

Answer (score 8):

in the export process from your server's PhpMyAdmin select Custom options, then - be sure to tick under Object Creation Options the next option:

Add DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION / EVENT statement

than try to re import the DB

hope it helped

Comment: @Ritchie please accept if answer is correct. thanks :)